# Error in running jest test with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

It's my first time to write tests. I'm writing tests for a ReactJS app wrote with hooks, and testing using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library).

Here's my functional component:

```
const ItemDetails = ({ item }) => {
  const { code } = item;
  const { getBarcode } = useStationContext();

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          getBarcode(code);
        }}
        style={{ float: 'right' }}
      >
        Print Barcode
      </Button>
      <List
        bordered
        dataSource={formatData(item)}
        renderItem={({ title, value }) => (
          <List.Item>
            <List.Item.Meta
              description={
                <Wrapper>
                  <p>{upperCase(title)}</p>
                  <div>{value}</div>
                </Wrapper>
              }
            />
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ItemDetails;
```

and the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup } from 'react-testing-library';
import ItemDetails from '../containers/Items/ItemPage/ItemDetails';

afterEach(cleanup);

describe('formatData()', () => {
  it('Return Details about item', async () => {
    const { getByText, getByTestId, container, asFragment } = render(
      <ItemDetails
        item={{
          id: '296-c-4f-89-18',
          barcode: 'E-6',
        }}
      />,
    );

    global.console = {
      log: jest.fn(getByText, getByTestId, container, asFragment),
    };

    expect(global.console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
  });
});
```

When I run the test I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBarcode' of null

I don't know how can I fix this?

Comment: This likely depends on what useStationContext is. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case.

Comment: It's a Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectations are wrong because `console.log` isn't called anywhere. Mocking `console` object like `global.console = ...` is a bad practice because it persists between tests and can break things that depend on it, including test runner itself.

There's inconsistency with item `code` key, it was provided as `barcode`.

Context value is expected to be `undefined`, unless default value was provided. It should be provided in test.

It likely should be:

```
const getBarcodeMock = jest.fn();

const { getByText, getByTestId, container, asFragment } = render(
 <StationContext.Provider value={{ getBarcode: getBarcodeMock }}>
  <ItemDetails
    item={{
      id: '296-c-4f-89-18',
      code: 'E-6',
    }}
  />
 </StationContext.Provider>
);

// ...simulate button click...

expect(getBarcodeMock).toBeCalledWith('E-6');
```